# TeXStudio: Why can't pgfplots open gnuplot output anymore?

Tags: pgfplots, texstudio

Here's the minimum not working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    title={$0 = \gamma cos(\phi) - 1$},
    view={0}{90},
    xlabel=$\gamma$, ylabel=$\phi$,
    ]
        \addplot3[
        domain=1:1.5,
        domain y=0:6.2831853072,
        contour gnuplot={number=1},
        thick,
        ]
        {x*cos(deg(y)) - 1};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another example, which is known to work since its, borrowed from the answer to an existing question, also does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
empty line = jump % not strictly necessary, as this is the default behaviour in the development version of PGFPlots
] gnuplot {
    set contour base;
    set cntrparam levels discrete 0.003;
    unset surface;
    set view map;
    set isosamples 500;
    splot exp(x)*cos(y)-1;
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The very first time I run the *.tex file, I get the following errors and warnings:

```
line 21: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'contour_pgfplot_v2.pg> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. };
: No file contour_pgfplot_v2.aux.
line 22: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.
```

The second time, I only get the following:

```
line 21: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'contour_pgfplot_v2.pg> gnuplot <file>.gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file.. };
line 22: You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX Studio had an improper shutdown, due to a forced computer restart I had done earlier. This caused it to revert many of its settings, especially `--shell-escape` command line option for `pdflatex`. In particular, the *settings reverted to the last time I had saved them*, which is what *should* happen. Hence, these examples were not working. However, after setting the `--shell-escape` option again, things were working as usual.

In particular, looking at the errors in the more complete "Log" window, rather than "Messages" window gave the clue that the `--shell-escape` setting had disappeared.